# Prove that $a_{m+6} \equiv a_{m} \pmod{7}$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that the sequence defined by $a_{m+2} = 4a_{m+1}-2a_m, m \geq 1$ satisfies $a_{m+6} \equiv a_{m} \pmod{7}$.

I thought about proving this by induction, but I was wondering if there were an easier way of proving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use congruences and check $\;a_{m+3}\equiv -a_m\mod 7$.

Comment: How does that help prove the statement?

Comment: $a_{m+6}=a_{(m++3)+3}$.

Comment: How do we prove $a_{m+3} \equiv -a_m \pmod{7}$ using congruences?

Comment: Simple computation module $7$. Can you compute $a_{m+3}$ in function of $a_m$ and $a_{m+1}$?

Comment: We have $a_{m+3} = 4a_{m+2}-2a_{m+1} = 14a_{m+1}-8a_m$.

Comment: $14\equiv ?\;$ and $\;8\equiv ?\mod 7$?

Answer (score 0):

You can also show that, over $\mathbb{F}_7$, $a_n=A(-1)^n+B(-2)^n$ for fixed constants $A,B$ and for all $n$.